# Hide order of magnitude in Taylor series

Tags: python, sympy, taylor-series

I've been trying to familiarise myself with sympy and stumbled upon the series expansion.

For example:

```
series(cos(x),x, n=5)
```

prints:

```
1 - x**2/2 + x**4/24 + O(x**6)
```

I was wondering if there was a way of hiding the last part (`O(x**6)`) in the output, as in, it would print:

```
1 - x**2/2 + x**4/24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove O, use `removeO` method:

```
>>> series(cos(x),x, n=5).removeO()
x**4/24 - x**2/2 + 1
```

Side effect: the terms now print in opposite order since the expression is now a polynomial rather than an asymptotic expansion.